# MultiSelectField On Django Admin Not Showing Values

Tags: python, django

I am seeing my list's key (permit_num and passport_num) instead of my values (Work Permit and Passport) on my Django admin. How do I fix this?

For docs_good, it is showing "Yes" or "No". So it is good to me.

Everything else is doing fine but only for this one. Perhaps because I use an external package?

Here is my view.py:

```
from django.db import models
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

class Case(models.Model):
doc_choices = (
    ('permit_num', 'Work Permit'),
    ('passport_num', 'Passport'),    
)

doc_listed = MultiSelectField("Documents Received?", choices=doc_choices, default=False)

doc_good_choices = (
    ('y', 'Yes'),
    ('n', 'No'),
    )

docs_good = models.CharField("Documents Good To Go?", max_length=264, choices=doc_good_choices,default=False)
```

My admin.py script:

```
class CaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Case
    list_display = ('doc_listed', 'docs_good')

admin.site.register(Case, CaseAdmin)
```

Comment: I'd try removing the `default=False` from the MultiSelectField declaration.

Comment: Thanks Ben! Tried that but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
list_display = ('get_doc_listed_display', 'docs_good')
```